# What kind of rear derailleur is compatible with hanger on my bicycle

Tags: road-bike, derailleur-rear, derailleur-hanger

I have a Giant OCR (2004).  I need to replace the rear derailleur (10 speed long cage - triple front chain ring).
I've attached a picture of the hanger.
What type of derailleur would work with this configuration?  Not looking for the top of the line component, but a moderately priced.
Thank you.
Kevin
[image: front view with hanger attached]

Comment: Wow there's some definite scoring and road rash there !   I hope you're OK and the bike took the damage, not the rider.   Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 7):

The derailleur bolt is a standard part. Any derailleur would fit it. However, you need a derailleur that works with the rest of your drivetrain, which is a separate question. You can probably find NOS examples of this exact model on eBay.

Just in case there's any misunderstanding: in the picture, you've removed the derailleur hanger from the frame and left the derailleur on it. You should return the derailleur hanger to the frame and then remove the derailleur, unless the hanger is bent.

Comment: +1 concise answer

Comment: And to remove the derailleur from the hanger, there's a hex slot down in the hole.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, almost all derailers are compatible with any hanger. They just screw into the hanger using a standard M10x1 bolt. The issue most people have is with the compatibility of the hanger and the frame. For some frames it is hard to find a replacement hanger when the original one is damaged.

I see the bike was crashed. If the hanger is not bent, then you can reuse it, and you only need to replace the derailer. For the new derailer to work it needs to match:

- The mounting screw, [it is standard for almost all derailers](https://wheelsmfg.com/blog/standard-mount-vs-direct-mount-derailleur-hangers.html);
- The capacity it can handle, i.e the difference in teeth between the smallest and largest cog on the cassette;
- The shifter, i.e should be compatible with its number of clicks/speeds, and pull ratio.

[image]

If the hanger is bent, it may be repaired, you may find this video useful (and many other online resources, just look for "how to fix a bent derailer hanger", sometimes it can be fixed):